# SQL Update Table 1 when Table 2 contains a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update **lasstock** of table **s_articles** to 1 when **laststock** is 0 and is either in **categoryID** 242, 243 or 244 in table **s_articles_categories_ro**.

I came up with this SQL, which doesn't work.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.laststock = 1
FROM s_articles AS a
LEFT JOIN `s_articles_categories_ro` AS ac
ON a.id = ac.articleID
WHERE a.laststock=0 AND ac.categoryID IN (242,243,244)
```

I have these 2 tables:
**s_articles**

| id | laststock |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |

**s_articles_categories_ro**

| id | articleID | categoryID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 242 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 6 | 4 | 21 |
| 7 | 1 | 244 |

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Its phpmyadmin with MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use *exists* correlated query here

```
update s_articles a
set laststock = 1
where laststock = 0
 and exists (
   select * from s_articles_categories_ro ac 
     where ec.categoryId in (242,243,244) 
       and ac.articleId = a.Id
   );
```

Comment: This works, but the answere below seems more elegant

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder perhaps! More generally, when querying data it's normally preferable to use *exists* where possible to do so as in most cases it's more performant.

Comment: Ok, thats good to know!
Do you have a good reference where i can see the performance differences in a chart or something like that?
Also ill use ur method due to that now

Comment: Not to hand and the ctieria and circumstances of course will vary, but *exists* will short-circuit and return as soon as its criteria are met, which can result in reading less rows; with a join, depending on where the optimiser is able to push the filtering predicate you can end up reading and joining many more rows before filtering. Of course joining tables is necessary if you need to return data, but in this case exists is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` statement might need to use `JOIN` before `SET` in MySQL, and I think we might use `JOIN` instead of `OUTER JOIN`

```
UPDATE s_articles a
INNER JOIN `s_articles_categories_ro` AS ac
ON a.id = ac.articleID
SET a.laststock = 1
WHERE a.laststock = 0 AND ac.categoryID IN (242,243,244)
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you use "left join"?

Try this:

```
UPDATE s_articles
JOIN  s_articles_categories_ro ON s_articles.id = s_articles_categories_ro.articleID 
SET laststock = 1
WHERE s_articles.laststock=0 AND s_articles.categoryID IN (242,243,244)
```

Another option

Try this:

```
UPDATE s_articles SET laststock = 1
Where id in (
SELECT id from s_articles
JOIN  s_articles_categories_ro ON s_articles.id = s_articles_categories_ro.articleID 
WHERE s_articles.laststock=0 AND s_articles.categoryID IN (242,243,244)
)
```

Comment: Iam not an expert in SQL, so i don't know how to update when needing more than one table.
That was like my first try